# Bind to the output of a method of an injected class

Tags: java, scala, dependency-injection, guice

I have a class, say `Batsman` that depends on the output of a method, say `rules` of a class `Umpire`. The Umpire class is built by injecting dependencies, say `Country`.

My question is, what would be a right way to model this using Guice?

I feel like making the `Batsman` constructing using `Umpire` would be wrong as in terms of real world, he only needs to know the rules, not the whole `Umpire`.

Comment: Seems to me like Batman is dependent on umpire.

Comment: @RobertMoskal I clarified. My point is that Batsman shouldn't have to know the full Umpire. I'm okay in general passing a whole object when it reflects the real world usage but here it doesn't make sense.

Comment: Why not create a `ShoutsRules` interface containing the `rules()` method? Then you can inject just that interface into `Batsman` and have a binding to bind `ShoutsRules` to `Umpire`

Comment: @DanielBickler That's a good point. I should probably do that.

Comment: Now that I have a somewhat better understanding of DI, I think your answer is probably the canonical way to do it. Can you make an answer so it's more visible to others, I'll mark it as solved?